# How can I post a json object and a file to asp.net server with fetch

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, fetch

I'm a bit stuck here, I'm trying to post a json object from my indexedDb simultaneously with a IFormFile object to the server. The method that accepts it looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(BatchModel model, IFormFile vinFile)
    {
    //logic goes here
    }
```

This method worked earlier, before I had to store my batchModels as Json objects, and were just posted straight from the form with a POST. A lot has changed since then, and now the client will upload it as soon as he gets  online again from an offline state, with the following (simplified) method:

```
if (infoChanged === true) {
    fetchPromises.push(
        fetch('/Batch/Create/', {
            headers: new Headers({
                'Content-Type': 'application/javascript' //Tried this with multi-part/form
            }),
            credentials: 'same-origin',
            method: 'POST',
            body: batch //, vinFile
        })
    );
}
return Promise.all(fetchPromises);
```

For testing I tried to use the method with only the model filled, and the only thing I had to change was that I had to change in the C# code was adding a [FromBody] tag, but now I need the vinFile filled as well.
I tried it already with a FormData object, appending the batch and the vinFile with the same name as in the Create function. But that would result in both variables as null.

Answer (score 0):

The key feature you need to look at is your header.  You can change your response to JSON if you do header: { Content-Type: "application/json" }

You want something like this: You need to configure the type yourself.

```
fetch(myRequest).then(function(response) {
    var contentType = response.headers.get("content-type");
    if(contentType && contentType.includes("application/json")) {
      return response.json();
    }
    throw new TypeError("Oops, we haven't got JSON!");
  })
  .then(function(json) { /* process your JSON further */ })
  .catch(function(error) { console.log(error); });
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: If you're also trying to convert your type on the server side you might want to take a dive into NewtonSoft https://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Comment: Hey thanks for the response, but I'm trying to do a 'post' not a 'get'. And I cant change it to application/json because I'm trying to post both a json and a .csv file at the same time. I was thinking more about multipart/form-data, but that doesn't seem to work either.
I'll look into newtonsoft though!